# Removing hard water residue from Quartz

Tags: cleaning, countertops, quartz

I have very hard water and a dish rack.
Unbeknownst to me, under the dish rack, a few large hard water (calcium?) yellowish, rough feeling spots have formed.

How should one go about removing these without damaging the Quartz. ([My specific surface](http://www.lgviaterausa.com/products/289/166) if that matters)

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic but I use a product called CLR , calcium Lime and Rust remover the only place I have found it to damage is cement counters when left on for an extended time to remove a rust stain. It usually works in seconds.

Comment: Try vinegar. I use it to clean my car once in a while. You can use regular, cider, or cleaning.

Comment: Try using a catch tray under the dish rack.  The one I have hangs over the lip of the sink and drains into the sink.   Most inexpensive dish racks come with them.  Seriously, you should really use one of those, otherwise you'll have standing water under them and all sorts of trouble will follow from water damage (of the plain kind) to bacteria and mold.

Comment: You can get a sample from the manufacturer or dealer and test out any cleaning products there.